# How to make observable in angular2 which updates value after interval?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-observables

I am creating observable in angular2.

I want to create a observable which will update the value after 2 seconds .
So far, I have created something like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'observable-demo',
  templateUrl: 'observabe-demo.component.html',
})
export class ObservabeDemoComponent implements OnInit {
   public data:any;
   public num:number;
   constructor() {

   //I want to update this observable value with fibonacci series after 2 seconds each.
   this.data=new Observable<any>(observer=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
         observer.next(32);  
      },2000);          
   });

   let subscriber=this.data.subscribe(
      value=>this.num=value,
      err=>console.log(err),
      ()=>console.log("Completed")
     );
   } 

}
```

Currently , after 2 seconds my observable updates the value with 32.

but I want to run this function repeatedly till value reaches 10000.

I want to store fibonacci series in this observable and print it.

is something like this possible with angular2 observables?

thanks.

Comment: For repeat you can use setInterval()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [interval()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) function on Observables:

```
return Observable
        .interval(2000) // time in ms
        .flatMap(() => {
            return nextNumber()
        });
```